# SpringSecutiry e JNDI problema de Autenticação

Tags: java, jsf, spring

Estou com um problema de autenticação quando adiciono o datasource no meu projeto, acontece que ao tentar fazer login é realizado a autenticação mas não a transição para a página pós-login. Utilizo o UserDetailsService customizado, consegue a conexão com o banco, mas não consegue autenticar, e não aparece nenhum erro o meu **context.xml** está :

```
i <Resource auth="Container" 
          name="jdbc/dbtest" 
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
          maxActive="100" 
          maxIdle="10" 
          maxWait="-1" 
          username="test" 
          password="test"
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbteste?autoReconnect=true"
          debugMode="true"
          validationQuery="SELECT 1">
```

O meu **hibernate.cfg.xml** está assim:

```
i <session-factory>

    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/dbtest</property><property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="connection.shutdown">true</property>
```

O meu **applicationContext** está assim:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" id="securityDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/dbtest"></jee:jndi-lookup>    
<b:bean id="loginBean" name="authenticationService" class="br.com.app.controller.AuthenticationService">
    <b:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"></b:property>
</b:bean>
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/index.xhtml"> 
  <form-login login-page="/login.xhtml" 
         always-use-default-target="true"
         default-target-url="/cadastro/central.xhtml"
         authentication-failure-url="/login.xhtml?login_error=1" />
  <logout invalidate-session="true" 
            logout-success-url="/index.xhtml" 
            delete-cookies="JSESSION"/>
</http>
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"> 
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
<b:bean id="userDetailsService" class="br.com.app.controller.UserDetailsServiceImpl"/>
```

o web.xml está assim:

```
<resource-ref>
     <description>DataSource</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/dbtest</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

E a implementação do **UserDetailsServiceImp** está assim:

```
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

private UsuarioDAO us;
@PersistenceContext
private Session sessao;

 public UserDetailsServiceImpl() {
     us = new UsuarioDAO();
    }

 @Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    return findByUsername(username);
}

private Usuario findByUsername(String username) {
    Usuario login;
    sessao = us.getSession();
    try {
        System.out.println("Entrou na Classe UserDetaisServiceImpl e procurando o usuário");
        Criteria cr = sessao.createCriteria(Usuario.class);
        cr.add(Restrictions.eq("email", username));

        login = (Usuario) cr.uniqueResult();
        System.out.println("Login: "+login.toString());
        if (login == null) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("Info", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "UserDetailsService: Não foi possivel fazer login, sua lincença expirou ou o login foi digitado incorretamente", "Esse usuário não existe!"));
        }
        if (!login.isCredentialsNonExpired()) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("Info", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "UserDetailsService: Não foi possivel fazer login, licença expirou", "Favor tente novamente!"));
            return null;
        } else {
            return login;
        }
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("UserDetailsService: Usuario nao encontrado: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        sessao.close();
    }
}
```

Testei aqui usando um login que não existe e retorna que o login está errado, já tentei de várias formas e não consigo, não consegue fazer a transição da página de login para a pagina pós-login.

Comment: Uma das possibilidades é que a sua página de login não esteja enviando corretamente os dados para o spring security. Veja se os nomes dos campos estão seguindo o padrão na requisição HTTP. JSF é campeão em estragar nomes. Você chegou a depurar e ver se o código de autenticação chega a ser executado?

Comment: Sim @utluiz ele faz autenticação, mas na hora da transição não vai.

Comment: Certo, mas se você digitar manualmente a página de pós-login ele vai? Ou ele sempre redireciona para o login de novo?

Comment: Outra coisa, não estou vendo onde você define a *ROLES* da aplicação. Tipo: `<intercept-url pattern='/login.htm*' filters='none'/>
    <intercept-url pattern='/**' access='ROLE_USER' />`. Além disso, seu usuário traz alguma *role* ou está vazio?

Comment: A resposta da sua primeira pergunta,@utluiz, não vai quando coloco a página pós login, e não redireciona para página de login, ja a sua segunda eu omitir, pois o código ficaria muito grande.

Comment: O interessante é que, quando eu dou o stop no tomcat, é executado os métodos que são normalmente executados pós-login.

Comment: Problemas de redirecionamento geralmente são causados porque o usuário não tem a permissão para ver a página de pós-login e ele acaba sendo redirecionado de volta como se houvesse uma falha. Mas para resolver isso tem que investigar o caso em todos os detalhes.

Comment: `<intercept-url pattern="/cadastro/*" access="isAuthenticated()"/>`

Comment: `<intercept-url pattern="/cadastro/*" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/info/*" access="permitAll"/>` Acredito que não seja, pois na página info o usuário entra, e quando está fazendo a autenticação é demonstrado no console Autenticação é satisfatório: true